# Pass filename to windows batch (.bat) script when double clicking so that it will run in octave

Tags: batch-file, octave

I'm new in using batch scripts, and moderately experienced with octave. I have a lot of data files I examine with octave functions and I am trying to set up so that I can double click on files with a custom extension to directly open octave functions. Think "when I double click on this text file, it opens in notepad."

To do this I've written a very basic `.bat` file and I've associated my .data files to open using this .bat file. The `.bat` file looks like this:

```
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\octave.vbs --no-gui --persist --eval myOctaveFunction.m
pause
```

I've tested it with a hard coded filename inside "myOctaveFunction." but instead i'd like to actually pass the data file name to myOctaveFunction when I double click on the data file. How do I do this? And, are batch scripts even the right way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Think you mean batch not bash.

Comment: I think you mean Explorer, not bash.

Comment: What operational system are you using? That makes all difference in the world.

Comment: @Alex: You can use %1 in your batch file to get the filename. I suggest you first play with a foo.bat, associated in your windoze explorer with your data file which contains `echo %1` and a `pause` at the end. If you see your datafilename here, then pass it to Octave with argc/argv OR using `--eval "myOctaveFunction (%1)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this batch file, which will echo a few specific items:

```
@echo off
echo My directory %cd%
echo Batchfile Name %0
echo File to run %1
pause
```

So %1 parameter will provide you with the filename itself.

You can also use it like this.

```
@echo off
echo My directory %cd%
echo Batchfile Name %~dpnx0
echo file to run %~dpnx1
pause
```

So in Short, this should work if you are running this the way I am thinking you do.

```
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\octave.vbs --no-gui --persist --eval myOctaveFunction('%1')
pause
```

Comment: Thanks! What worked in the end was using %1 and using "myOctaveFunction" without ".m" at the end. Which I guess is related to how the eval function in octave works. Took me a while to figure that one out. Final code looks like:

C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\octave.vbs --no-gui --persist --eval myOctaveFunction('%1').

Now to figure out how to avoid multiple instances of octave...

Comment: ok thanks for the comment! I will then edit the answer to reflect the change so it can help anyone else with future issues.

Comment: by multiple instances of octave do you mean it should not start another instance if one is already running?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. Right now every time i execute it opens a new octave instance. Which is no big deal since octave in no gui mode is pretty light... but somewhat unsightly, and takes an extra second or two to run because it has to start octave from scratch.

Comment: `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq appname.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "appname.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo myapp.exe running` then enter the name of the executable in appname.exe. you can then just build a if statement and not start octave until you find it has finished. it can run in a loop. if you want me to write the scipt portion for you, then create another question and I can post an answer

Comment: Hi, just to be clear though, what I want is: if octave is not running, start a new instance to load the data. If octave IS running, load the data in that instance. I don't want to just print out a message, if that makes any sense. In any case, I'll post a new question about it and link it here when I've done that. I'm not sure what I want is entirely possible. On the other hand programs like notepad++ do exactly that somehow, but they probably use something more sophisticated than batch files.