# Call function in existing instance of Octave from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, octave

I look at a lot of custom data (which is stored in custom .data files) in Octave. To help me load and look at them more quickly, I wrote a batch file so that I can double click on a .data file and run my custom Octave function on it, "myFunction(filename)". I've associated the .data extension to my batch file so that it's the default program to open them. The code for this file is below:

echo on
C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\octave.vbs  -q --no-gui --persist --eval data1=myFunction('%1');

I can then further analyze the data because it's loaded into the "data1" variable in Octave.

The only problem with this system is that the batch file opens a new instance of Octave every time I double click on a .data file. This means that I can't load two data sets in the same Octave environment to compare them.

Is there any way I can double click to open and call an existing instance of Octave if one exists? This way, my data sets would load up in the same environment.

@gerhard-barnard showed me the beginning of an answer in comments here: [Pass filename to windows batch (.bat) script when double clicking so that it will run in octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724855/pass-filename-to-windows-batch-bat-script-when-double-clicking-so-that-it-wil). I can use:

> tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq octave-gui.exe"

which returns info on the currently existing Octave instances. However, I'm not sure how I can use the PID, say, to pass a command to that instance of octave. If this isn't directly possible, is there a workaround to making this work in a roundabout way (write a file to disk, then load both into a new session for example)? I look at so many data files that it is definitely worth my time to make this work, and have the ability to load multiple files in the same instance.